# Is there a connection between Sith and Naboo?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, sith

I've recently seen some stuff written about a connection between Naboo and the Sith.

Overall, the guy said that Naboo has a lot of Sith history. In particular, here are some of the things he wrote:

- Exar Kun is a very distant relative of Padme Amidala
- Jedi are hated in Naboo
- Naboo has long history with the Sith, it belonged to the ancient Sith Empire
- The dark side is strong on Naboo, especially near plasma mines
- One of the conditions with which Naboo joined the republic - the Jedi should not descend to the planet

I've read couple of books from expanded lore, but I am by no means an expert in the canon/legends.

This stuff seems a bit weird. I haven't seen anything about this mentioned in the books I've read and I didn't find anything useful in Google.

Now a question - is this something from canon? If yes, where can I find more information about this? I guess this is taken from some book.

Comment: What was the book name? It would help if you provide more sources.

Comment: Your question title and question in your description are not asking the same thing. One is asking if there is a connection between Sith and Naboo, the other is asking whether the information you found that does connect the two is canon.

Comment: According to [this](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wookieepedia:Canon_policy), what is canon is what is shown in the original trilogy, prequel trilogy, Clone Wars (tv & movie), Rebels, _Insider_ fiction, Databank information, all the officially licensed novels/comics/material released since 2014's _A New Dawn_. This doesn't answer your question, just giving you a pointer as to what is considered canon since the Mouse purchased Star Wars.

Comment: All of that stuff was wiped from current canon.

Comment: @TimSparrow: That's the problem, the guy didn't say from where he took this info. I was really curious from where he got it, hence this question

Comment: @Ghoti and Chips 3: The title and the content of the question are related - essentially the guy said that there is a strong connection between Naboo and the Sith, and the bullet points are examples of concrete things he said

Comment: So this is from what is called "legends" universe?

Comment: I never heard for any of this even in Legends. Novel Darth Plagueis has some background on Naboo, but none of the things you mentioned.

Comment: In regards to "Exar Kun is a very distant relative of Padme Amidala", it seems relevant to observe that royalty has often had mixed bloodlines (compared to their subjects), due to diplomatic marriages. That's no proof in and of itself, but it stands to reason that this can also apply in-universe unless explicitly contradicted.

Comment: @Flater The Queen of Naboo is an elected office with term limits, quite different from the hereditary monarchies you're referencing.  No, I don't know why the Naboo would vote for a 14-year-old girl to be Queen (I can speculate, but I don't think that's relevant to this question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Not Really.

I'll go through this point by point.

> **Exar Kun is a very distant relative of Padme Amidala**

Nothing I can find supports this claim. [None of Padmé's ancestors beyond two of her grandparents are known](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/House_Naberrie), and Exar Kun had no known relatives.

> **Jedi are hated in Naboo**

Nothing in the films or *The Clone Wars* seems to support this. At no point do any of the human citizens of Naboo object to the presence of Jedi.

> BOSS NASS : Wesa wish no nutten in yousa tings, outlaunder, and wesa no
>   care-n about da Naboo.

Boss Nass doesn't particularly like Qui-Gon or Obi-Wan, at least at first, but it's out of a general xenophobia towards non-gungans, not a specific hatred of the Jedi.

> **Naboo has long history with the Sith, it belonged to the ancient Sith Empire**

Nope, there were actually quite a few [Sith Empires](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_Empire_(disambiguation)) before the events of the main series, but [Naboo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Naboo/Legends#History) belonged to none of them

> **The dark side is strong on Naboo, especially near plasma mines.**

This is incorrect, but it's not as far from the truth as previous points. Naboo as a whole is never mentioned to be particularly strong in the Dark Side. However, canonically, Maul did apparently leave a Dark Side presence felt decades later, as shown in *Princess Leia*.

[image]

Additionally, in the Legends continuity, [Darth Plagueis was deeply involved in Naboo's Plasma industry](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ars_Veruna#The_election_of_65_BBY), though nothing about the mines themselves were inherently strong in the Dark Side.

> **One of the conditions with which Naboo joined the republic - the Jedi should not descend to the planet**

Again, I can find nothing to support this. At no point in *The Phantom Menace*, subsequent films, or *The Clone Wars* is it stated that the Jedi aren't supposed to be there.

---

The only significant connection between the Sith and Naboo is the fact that [Darth Sidious was from there](http://www.starwars.com/databank/emperor-palpatine-darth-sidious). However, the Sith had no presence there historically, and it was not a Dark Side-imbued planet.